# timeout with apache & php w/ each virtual host has his own user process

Tags: apache-2.2, php, fastcgi

I have 10 unix users in /home/.
Each user is for a specific subdomain for example user www in /home/www/public_html is for www.mywebsite. blog in /home/blog/public_html is for blog.mywebsite.

90% is php and 10% ror

for the moment i use apache + fastcgi that use SuexecUserGroup to setup the process with the good user.

it seems to works but i have a strange behavior where after a few hours/days, the server stop answering (timeout) but the cpu load is still very low (it's a big server), the apache status display lot of "W" Sending Reply states but there's still 50 idle workers so it should be able to answer.

in the older server (lot of slower) we add only one user and using mod_php and we never had this issue.

is there another way to do that without fastcgi and SuexecUserGroup or do you know what's going wrong?